# Include Lead Forensics code in all pages

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm trying to include the tracking code Lead Forensics gave me. The code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.path-trail.com/js/11111.js"></script>
<noscript><img src="http://www.path-trail.com/11111.png" style="display:none;" /></noscript>
```

I've tried creating a block with only this in the body, but it doesn't render in the page (when I check the generated code with 'view source code' on the browser, it isn't there). I don't know if it's the correct way to do it. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this is by placing the script in the code for the theme.

You may be able to pretend this is another script and use a Drupal module that adds a script to the theme.

An issue you may be having by using a block is that unless you have the right permissions and also are careful to preserve this code as source, Drupal may try to alter what you enter for security or because you don't have permission to add a script.

We are a user/partner of Drupal and LeadForensics.